# How do you check if userinput was something else?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to check what the user input was and if it was something else, it would print("") and continue.

Right now I have

```
userasnwer = int(input("reply with Hi or Hello or Yo"))

 if userasnwer == "Hi" or "Hello" or "Yo": 

  from random import randint 
  number = randint(1,3)

  if number == 1:
   print(awnser1)

  if number ==2:
   print(awnser2)

  if number == 3:
   print(awnser3)
```

But it justs prints one of them for any response. Can someone help me with how to respond only from the given?

Comment: Well this would throw an exception in a number of your cases because `int('Hi')` throws a `ValueError`. Use `if <cond>: ... elif <cond>: ... else: ...`

Comment: if userasnwer in ["Hi", "Hello", "Yo"]: is what you are probably looking for

Comment: Can you post running code so we can see what you are doing? And 4 spaces per indent - its hard to spot logical blocks with 1 space.... its not like we are running out of spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think your issue stems from the line,

```
if userasnwer == "Hi" or "Hello" or "Yo":
```

Here python checks if one of the three conditions is `True`.

First, it checks `userasnwer == "Hi"`. Then, `"Hello"` or `"Yo"`. If you open up a Python REPL or run a small program like,

```
if "hello":
    print("Hi!")
```

You'll see that `"hello"` evaluates to `True`. Do you see why your program runs incorrectly now?

**Edit:** I see your real question now but there was a bug hidden underneath that I helped squash for you. After your `if-statement` that checks for the `useranswer` you'll just need an `else-statement`. i.e..

```
if useranswer == 'Hi' or useranswer == 'Hello' or useranswer == 'Yo':
    # insert your logic here
else:
    print("No greeting!")
```

Note a more 'pythonic' way to write that first line would be,

```
if useranswer in ['Hi', 'Hello', 'Yo']:
```

This is a good link for [Python Operators](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/operators)

Comment: I'm pretty new to python, although I started with it, I advanced more in Lua. So most of my methods aren't that 'pythonic'

Answer (score 0):

```
userasnwer = input("reply with Hi or Hello or Yo")
if userasnwer == "Hi" or userasnwer == "Hello" or userasnwer == "Yo": 
    from random import randint 
    number = randint(1,3)

    if number == 1:
       print(awnser1)

    if number ==2:
       print(awnser2)

    if number == 3:
       print(awnser3)
```